# FileZilla won't react on commands from my java FTP server

Tags: java, ftp

I write my own Java FTP server. Until recently I used PUttY to debug my control telnet connection and everything seemed fine - I had successful two-way communication. Now I try to debug my server with FileZilla, but it does not seem to read my text, nor to send some to server, so it just hangs and wait for something.
Control connection class

```
public class ControlConnection extends Thread {
private enum OperationMode {
    ACTIVE, PASSIVE
}
private final Map<String, Supplier<String>> COMMANDS;
private String[] userTokens;

private User user;
private String userLogin;
private boolean authenticated;
private boolean dataConnected;
private boolean userExists;
private final Socket socket;
private DataInputStream inputStream;
private DataOutputStream outputStream;
private DataConnection ftpSession;
private OperationMode operationMode;
private String errorMessage;

public ControlConnection(Socket socket) {
    super(ControlConnection.class.toString());
    this.socket = socket;

    // constants initialization
    authenticated = false;
    dataConnected = false;

    // commands initialization
    COMMANDS = new HashMap<>();
    // commands init
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        sendGreetings();
        IOProcessing.writeBytes(outputStream, pasvCommand());;
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            sendGreetings();
            String input = IOProcessing.readBytes(inputStream);
            if (!(input.equals("")))
                System.out.println(input);
            if (!checkInput(input))
                continue;
            userTokens = input.split(" ");
            String command = userTokens[0].toUpperCase();
            String answer = COMMANDS.get(command).get();              
            outputStream.writeBytes(answer);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
private boolean commonCheck() {
    // some checks
    return true;    
}
private String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}
public void sendGreetings() {
    String greetings = String.format("220 Control connection established: %s", getConnectionInfo());
    IOProcessing.writeBytes(outputStream, greetings);
}
public String getConnectionInfo() {
    String info = String.format("%s: %d %s",
            socket.getInetAddress().toString(), socket.getPort(), user != null ? user.getUsername(): "");
    return info;
}
// input/output proccessing functions
public boolean checkInput(String input) {
    // checks
    return true;
}

// commands functions
private String pasvCommand() {
    if (operationMode == OperationMode.PASSIVE) {
        errorMessage = "Already in passive mode.%n";
        return errorMessage;
    }
    String answer;
    new ListenToSocket().start();
    answer = String.format("227 Entering Passive Mode (%s, %d)",
        "127.0.0.1", DataConnection.PORT);
    operationMode = OperationMode.PASSIVE;
    return answer;
    }
private class ListenToSocket extends Thread {
    public ListenToSocket() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket ftpSocket =
                    new ServerSocket(DataConnection.PORT);
            ftpSession =
                    DataConnection.getDataConnection(ftpSocket.accept());
            if (ftpSession != null) {
                ftpSession.start();
                dataConnected = true;
                String greetings = "Data connection established: " + ftpSession.getConnectionInfo();
                IOProcessing.writeBytes(outputStream, greetings);
            } else {
                dataConnected = false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

also, server does not get user credentials, entered in FileZilla - input from server is always empty
IOProcessing class

```
public class IOProcessing {
private static final Charset UTF8_CHARSET;
static {
    UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
}

public static String readBytes(DataInputStream inputStream) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        int len = inputStream.available();
        if (len == 0) {
            return result;
        }
        byte[] byteInput = new byte[len];
        inputStream.readFully(byteInput, 0, len);
        result = new String(byteInput, "UTF-8").trim();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

output FileZlla log
Status: Resolving address of localhost
Status: Connecting to [::1]:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show us the `writeBytes`. So I can only guess that you are not sending `\r\n` after the messages sent to the client. Particularly after the welcome message. So FileZilla keeps waiting forever for it, as any FTP client would do.

Comment: `writeBytes` is implemened in `DataOutputStream`, so I did not change anything. Is sending `\r\n` so important?

Comment: I mean `IOProcessing.writeBytes`

Comment: Or course, it is important! How else could the FTP client identify end of the message?

Comment: Now it works, thanks a lot! Strangely that PUttY worked fine without `\r\`

Comment: PuTTY is not FTP client. - You should read FTP specification, before trying to implement FTP server.